# SurveyJS results

Tags: node.js, surveyjs

I'm implementing surveys on the company's internal website using SurveyJS -> [surveyjs.io](https://surveyjs.io/) integrated with Node.js. All the survey results are stored in the local database in the JSON format. I've finished the management part and can store, modify and present surveys.

Did anybody work with the SurveyJS and know how to present survey results in the nice table or graph? I cannot find any documentation on their website or working example how to implement it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use datatables for that. Even in the WordPress plugin for surveyjs they used that. Refer the code.

https://datatables.net/

https://github.com/surveyjs/surveyjs-wordpress

Comment: Also you can check the surveyjs-nodejs example: https://github.com/surveyjs/surveyjs-nodejs. It uses datatables too. But you can integrate any other solution with SurveyJS because it is just json on the output.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [SurveyJS Dashboard Library](https://surveyjs.io/dashboard) to visualize survey results. For more information, refer to:

- Demos: https://surveyjs.io/dashboard/examples/plain-data/reactjs
- Documentation: https://surveyjs.io/dashboard/documentation/get-started-react.